# How to do Undo/Redo without states?

Tags: undo, undo-redo

I'm working on a sample library instrument that uses KSP, which I doubt anyone here knows and is a pretty basic and limited language.

I'm trying to figure out how I could implmenet a undo/redo system for interacting with my UI.
I already have a preset system set up that utilizes "last_value" arrays that I've declared for every group of UI elements. That works fine since it only has to remember the last active value change that each UI control received.

So when saving and loading presets, I only have to save all current UI values to a master preset array, or load and apply all values from a saved data file array.
But how would I consider all the history of edits that have been made?
Just saving the values up to a x-th maximum undo step is one thing, but I also have to remember which UI control was triggered in which order?

I'm a beginner and don't know any other languages, so my head is smoking right now trying to conceive how to actually do this.

I'm grateful for any tips and suggestions!

Comment: Use an undo stack and a redo stack. Storing application states in them is usually the simplest approach. An alternative is to use the command pattern with undo methods included a part of the command interface. With that way you store instances of your commands on the stacks. But my experience is that having to implement an undo method for everything you do is onerous. On the other hand if you set up Memento right it is easy to maintain.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!
For now I've solved it in a way that every undo/redo does the same procedure as when I load a preset, which just means that every UI update also needs to call a function which updates the value states in a 2d array.

Forgive me but I didnt understand most of what you are saying, as I am a beginner. Would you mind enlightening me so I can learn?
What is a stack?
What is memento?
Is "on ui_control", that triggers every time the ui control is moved, a command pattern?

Comment: A stack is a first-in/first-out collection. You would need to use that if you want to be able to undo more than one action. The Memento Pattern is a way of implementing undo/redo by storing states. on_ui_control is an event handler, which is a method that is invoked when a particular event occurs. The Command Pattern is a way of encapsulating the information you need to perform an action.

Comment: Alright cool. Thanks for the clarification.
I'm learning so much as I go!